# How to generate a df with different purchased items [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to built a df with 100 purchase tickets, with different number of items purchased (1 to 15); the items codes (1 to 100).
Each row is a ticket.

I try df.append inside the loop but id did not works for me.

I would appreciate your help to solve this issue.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

random.seed(521) 

low =1 #the codes for the items are between 1 and 100

high =100

for i in range(100): #purchase sequences

    for j in range(1,16):#items per ticket
        seq1=random.sample(range(low, high), j)

        print(seq1)

print(seq1)
```

`

My df must look like (sample wit 5 items max):

[13]

[1, 40]

[33, 53, 92]

[23, 46, 13, 84]

[42, 35, 40, 71, 17]

[5]

[54, 95]

[23, 44, 87]

[17, 11, 50, 41]

[36, 94, 62, 1, 23]

Comment: Your code only includes `print`. Where do you add anything to a data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#creates a dataframe with 1 column of arrays of random values
pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([[random.randint(1, 100) for __ in range(random.randint(1, 15))] for _ in range(100)]))
#creates a dataframe with 1 column for each values and NaNs for unfilled rows
pd.DataFrame([[random.randint(1, 100) for __ in range(random.randint(1, 15))] for _ in range(100)])
```

Comment: Thanks so much; it gives me a [100 rows x 1 columns] df but I need a df 100X15 to identify the individual items:it1, it2,....,it15. If there are missing items some NANs will be marked